# Datasource Issue 'url' attribute not specified after removing database

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was making a SpringBoot application that would interact with MsSQL but the goals of the project have changed and I no longer need to use a database. After clearing my Application.properties of the Database details and deleting the Dependency from the pom.xml I am still receiving this error.

```
Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.27</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: If you've removed your db, then why are you using spring-data-jpa? I think that's what's causing your issue, also remove that dependency

Comment: @Spider I am using JPA because everything I've seen uses JPA. I'm not sure how else to setup my program without it. Is it a requirement that I need a database with JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the initial question: you should remove your **spring-boot-starter-data-jpa** dependency as @mohit-singh said as well.

To your second question in discussion with @spider."I'm not sure how else to setup my program".

Answer is: **it depends on what you want**. More precisely, autoconfigure of spring is what you need to mind. You probably have [@SpringBootApplication](https://dzone.com/articles/the-springbootapplication-annotation-example-in-jaannotation) 
 in your program like many of us. It is responsible for auto configuration of beans. One of beans spring configure for you is JPA bean. JPA autoconfiguration will look up for appropriate properties in your **application.properties** file and will not find the 'url' for example and of course will display the error you see. I hope it hepls.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I see that now.

Answer (score 0):

I can still see the spring data JPA dependency in your pom.

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
      </dependency>
```

This should be removed.